# Morphological image processing

Tags: image, image-processing

i am working on a project where i need to do some image processing, where i am not an expert.
I have an image obtained from QEMSCAN technology,[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSp7z.png) pink pixels represent the existence of the gold. there are 3 types of gold, type 1 where the connected pink pixels are surrounded with white ones. type 2 when the connected pink pixels are surrounded with white and another color.
type 3 where the pink area is connected with another colors except white.
I did some morphological image processing to isolate each area containing gold, but I'm blocked right now how i can determine to which type belong each pink area
thanks in advance

determine the type of gold
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZpuO.jpg)

Comment: Can you show in the image what your expected output should be? As far as I can tell, all the pink regions are connected to both white and green, so they’re all type 2?

Comment: hi, this is just an example. there would be another images that fit the other criterias

Comment: I am supposed to find the percentage of each type in the image

Comment: If you are going to show your expected results on a marked-up image, please give us BOTH the unmarked original AND marked images separately. Thanks.

Comment: let us take this image as an example of possible input [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZpuO.jpg) and let us suppose that we have 100 pink pixels in total, we have 50 pink pixels belong to type 1, 25 to type 2 and the rest to type 3. my program is supposed to give these results : in the region where this image was taken (using QEMSCAN technology) there are 50% of   type1_gold, 25 % of type2_gold and 25% of type3. thanks

Comment: There appear to be 2 shades of green... significant? Are yellow and cyan and grey to be ignored? Please click [edit] and put the actual image in there where it belongs, rather than in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: No matter what the color is (while it is not white or pink), yellow grey cyan ... are the same. in reality the pink color represents the gold, the white one  represents the non-useful part of the ground, and each color of the rest represent a mineral that we can exploit . so i'm not interested in which mineral is associated to the gold, i just need to know that there is another mineral to classify it .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible approach:

- make all the pink pixels white and everything else black
- do a dilation and find the coordinates of the additional pixels
- check the colour(s) of the additional pixels in the original image

Comment: first of all thank you for your time. i did transform the image to the  binary form. but when i do a dilation i loose the original coordinates of pink pixels. how can i  find the coordinates of additional pixels. I'm using python

Comment: Dilate a copy and subtract the original.